# How to screencast a Microsoft Surface application?

Tags: pixelsense

For demo purpose I would like to screencast my Surface application, but I don't really now how to do that. I tried to use the Surface Simulator and the Camtasia Studio to capture the simulator screen. The problem here is that if the Camtasa screen capture is running, so I can't use the mouse anymore to interact with the Surface simulator, because the simulator looses focus and the error message `Simulation is disabled because the Simulator is partly obscured` appears. So i tried to record a script and playing this script automatically while capturing the screen. This would work, but it limits the thing I can show, because for example when using ScatterViewItems it is not possible to forecast where it will appear on the screen and therefore I can't use a script in this point.

Therefore I'm looking for a way to screencast a Surface application while I'm interacting with it with my fingers. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use a real Surface with a camera mounted over the Surface so people can see both the screen and your fingers/objects.  That's what all the pros do - this is a much more effective way of conveying to the viewer how awesome your app is.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any other ideas if this is not possible for various reasons?

Comment: nope, sorry.  never tried it any other way